# R create new data.frame from old one according to column values

Tags: r

I have this simple data.frame

```
x=c(1,2,3,4,5,6)
y=c(5,6,1,2,4,5)
z=c(1,1,1,2,2,2)

data=data.frame(x,y,z)
```

I want to get

data1=

```
  x y z
1 1 5 1
2 2 6 1
3 3 1 1
```

and

data2=

```
  x y z
4 4 2 2
5 5 4 2
6 6 5 2
```

accordig to Z values

Comment: Try `split` ie. `split(data, data$z)` and use `list2env` if you need separate data.frame objects. ie. `list2env(setNames(split(data, data$z), paste0('data',1:2)), envir=.GlobalEnv)`

Comment: You can find useful answers [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17695443/r-split-dataframe-by-levels-of-a-factor-and-name-dataframes-by-those-levels), [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9713294/split-data-frame-based-on-levels-of-a-factor-into-new-data-frames) or [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19327020/in-r-how-to-split-subset-a-data-frame-by-factors-in-one-column).

Comment: use subset, like subset(data, z==1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
split(data, z)
```

this is a list

Comment: with `list <- split(data, data$z) A <- list[[1]] B <- list[[2]]`, you can access the new data.frames